# Async method that returns result and Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to design a public method that returns a quick result and, if needed, kicks off a long-running background task.

The result is retrieved within the method pretty quickly, and once it is retrieved it needs to be immediately available to the caller, without waiting for the potential background task to complete.

The background task is either not needed at all, or it must run for a significant amount of time - longer than the caller and all other logic in the program would take to complete without it.

Looking through the MS docs, the best design option I can come up with is to return two things from this method: the result, as well as a Task for the background task.

I don't see a better way to do this, but there are some downsides: first, the responsibility for making sure the background task completes falls on the caller of the method, even though the caller really just wants to consume the immediate result and not be concerned with the behind-the-scene stuff. Second, it is awkward to return null if the background task isn't needed to begin with: now the caller must ensure the task isn't null, in addition to making sure it completes if it is null.

**What other options are available for this sort of situation?**

Here's an example of what my current design looks like:

```
public async Task<Tuple<string, Task>> GetAndSave() {
    var networkResult = await GetFromNetworkAsync();
    if (NeedsToSave(networkResult)) {
        var saveTask = SaveToDiskAsync(networkResult);
        return new Tuple<string, Task>(networkResult, saveTask);
    }
    else {
        return new Tuple<string, Task>(networkResult, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically a regular `public Task Method()` could return `null` and it doesn't guarantee that the caller actually awaits it, so what your doing really isn't that different.  You could return `Task.CompletedTask` instead of `null` to avoid an exception or forcing the caller to check for `null`.

Comment: I guess you can have a tuple of a delegate and immediate result (just replacing Task with a delegate in your example). Then you can return a method that does the null check and executes other actions in the background. Now the responsibility of a caller of GetAndSave becomes to consume the result and  call the delegate.

Comment: What is the type of the app? Is it [ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> first, the responsibility for making sure the background task completes falls on the caller of the method, even though the caller really just wants to consume the immediate result and not be concerned with the behind-the-scene stuff.

If it's important to make sure the background task completes then instead of returning the `Task` you could hand it off to another object (that has been injected into the class that has your `GetAndSave` method). For example:

```cs
public class Foo
{
  readonly Action<Task> _ensureCompletion;

  public Foo(Action<Task> ensureCompletion)
  {
    _ensureCompletion = ensureCompletion;
  }

  public async Task<string> GetAndSaveAsync() // Your method
  {
    string networkResult = await GetFromNetworkAsync();
    if (NeedsToSave(networkResult))
    {
      Task saveTask = SaveToDiskAsync(networkResult);
      _ensureCompletion(saveTask); // This is a synchronous call... no await keyword here. And it returns `void`
    }
    return networkResult;
  }

  Task<string> GetFromNetworkAsync() {...}
  bool NeedsToSave(string x) {...}
  Task SaveToDiskAsync(string x) {...}
}
```

Now you can inject whatever follow-up behavior you desire for the `saveTask`. For example, you could write stuff out to the console depending on how it goes:

```cs
async Task DoStuff()
{
  var foo = new Foo(async task =>
  //                ^^^^^ More on this in a moment
  {
    try
    {
      await task;
      Console.Writeline("It worked!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.Writeline(e.ToString());
    }
  });

  var immediateResult = await foo.GetAndSaveAsync();
  // do stuff with `immediateResult`
}
```

Now, the thing that might be confusing about this (and the power behind this type of solution) is how you can have a synchronous call on the one hand:

```cs
_ensureCompletion(saveTask); // This is a synchronous call... no await keyword here
```

...that does asynchronous things:

```cs
var foo = new Foo(async task => ...);
//                ^^^^^ This statement lambda is asynchronous
```

(The injected delegate might even write out to the console on a different thread than whatever thread called `GetAndSaveAsync()`!)

There's no magic here. It all comes down to [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=net-5.0) and the inner workings of async/await.

When the compiler encounters the `await` keyword (in an `async` context) then it will do a few things:

- Turn everything after the `await` into a *continuation* (basically a delegate with some state)
- Replace the `await` keyword with something like `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(continuation)`

In other words, this:

```cs
async void EnsureCompletion(Task task)
{
  try
  {
    await task;
    Console.Writeline("It worked!");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.Writeline(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

...gets turned into something like this:

```cs
void EnsureCompletion(Task task)
{
  try
  {
    task.ContinueWith(t => SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ =>
    {
      if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
      {
        Console.Writeline("It worked!");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.Writeline(task.Exception.ToString());
      }
    });
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.Writeline(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

As you can see, `EnsureCompletion` is an entirely synchronous function that does (almost) the exact same thing as its asynchronous form. Notice how it returns `void` and everything. This is how you can jam an *asynchronous* statement lambda into a delegate parameter that has a *synchronous* signature.

I hinted that the console writing might happen on a totally different thread. That's because async/await is orthogonal to threading. It depends on whatever [the currently assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.setsynchronizationcontext?view=net-5.0) implementation of `SynchronizationContext` is programmed to do. Unless you're using WPF or WinForms then by default there will be no `SynchronizationContext` and continuations (the things that get passed to `SynchronizationContext.Post`) will just be tossed over to whatever thread happens to be free in the default thread pool.

> Second, it is awkward to return null if the background task isn't needed to begin with: now the caller must ensure the task isn't null, in addition to making sure it completes if it is null.

I'm of the opinion that `null` was a design mistake in C#. (Ask me what some other ones are :) ). If you return `null` from this method:

```cs
public Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
  return null; // Compiles just fine
}
```

...then anyone who uses it will encounter a `NullReferenceException` when they `await` it.

```cs
async Task Blah()
{
  await DoSomethingAsync(); // Wham! NullReferenceException :(
}
```

(the reason why comes back to how the compiler desugurs the `await` keyword)

...and it's awkward to have to check for nulls everywhere.

Much better would be to just return `Task.CompletedTask` as [@juharr said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644325/async-method-that-returns-result-and-task#comment119564809_67644325).

But if you just hand off the background task like I showed above then you don't have to worry about this.